# Asp.net WebApi .net Core request return 404

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm new to Asp.net (.Net Core) Web API.
I made AdminController but when i requesting the URL localhost:52054/API/admin/get  i got 404 not found on fiddler.
Here is my AdminController & Startup.cs
[AdminController Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFyjr.png)

```
    namespace Api2017_1.Controllers
{
    [Produces("application/json")]
    [Route("api/Admin")]
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        // GET: api/Admin
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<BsonDocument> Get()
        {
            const string cs = "mongodb://localhost:27017";
            var client = new MongoClient(cs);
            var db = client.GetDatabase("store");
            var coll = db.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("admins");
            using (var cursor = await coll.Find(new BsonDocument()).ToCursorAsync())
            {
                while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
                {
                    foreach(var doc in cursor.Current)
                    {
                        return doc;
                    }
                }

            }
            return (BsonDocument)0;
        }
```

[Startup.cs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yehbv.png)

```
    public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Can anyone guide me where i made mistake.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Code is "text" and not images. Put the "text" of your code in the question.

Comment: @nabish-khan : `try localhost:52054/API/admin` url

Answer (score 0):

You are requesting incorrect url. Use **localhost:52054/API/admin** instead with a request type as Get.